# Python reference to callback in dictionary

Tags: python, callback

I have a class that specifies a set of callback functions (shown here as `cb1` and `cb2`).  I keep a map of these which I want to call after some event.

```
class Foo:
    cb1 = None
    cb2 = None

    def test(self, input):
        for (name, callback) in map:
            if name == input:
                if callback: callback()
                ...

    map = {'one':cb1, 'two':cb2}

def mycallback():
    print "mycallback()"

f = Foo()
f.cb1 = mycallback  # Register our callback
f.test('one')     # Nothing happens
```

Can you spot the problem?

What happens, is that when the class is initialized, the *values* of `cb1` and `cb2` (which are both `None`) are copied into the map.  So even after a user 'registers' the callback (by assigning to `cb1`), the value in the map is still `None` and nothing gets called.

Since there's no such thing as 'by reference' in Python, how do I remedy this?

Comment: Nitpick: everything is passed 'by reference' in Python. But it's by reference, not by *name*: if you rebind the name to another object, that doesn't update other references to whatever the name was pointing to.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why not make your class explicitly handle registration?

```
import collections

class Foo(object):
    handlers = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.handlers = collections.defaultdict(set)

    def register(self, event, callback):
        self.handlers[event].add(callback)

    def fire(self, event, **kwargs):
        for handler in self.handlers.get(event, []):
            handler(**kwargs)

foo = Foo()
foo.register('one', mycallback)
foo.fire('one')
```

Comment: You're right. My dictionary is actually more complex than I presented - it has references to functions for parsing, and other things, so I initially overlooked this as not a compatible solution. But seeing it now, it is quite obviously the best way to do this. Thank you!

Comment: Helpful example on how to trigger the function using **kwargs.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24240274/typeerror-functionself-item-kwargs-takes-exactly-2-arguments-3-given

Answer (score 1):

Add a registration function.  In Foo class:

```
def register(self, name, cb): self.map[name] = cb
```

and instead of:

```
f.cb1 = mycallback
```

use:

```
f.register('one', mycallback)
```

Comment: Thanks for this - the other guy had just beat you to it.  BTW, my OP had a typo - I had `cb1 = mycallback` instead of `f.cb1 = mycallback` so you may want to edit your answer to reflect.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to set a different variable for customizing the callback than the one that is actually used to execute it? If you use the same variable, the problem disapears.

With some syntactic sugar it could look like this:

```
class CallbackMap(object):
    pass

class Foo(object):
    callbacks = CallbackMap()

    def test(self, input):
        callback = getattr(Foo.callbacks, input)
        if callback: callback()

# setup defaults
Foo.callbacks.one = None
Foo.callbacks.two = some_default_callback

# customize
def mycallback():
    print "mycallback()"

f = Foo()
Foo.callbacks.one = mycallback  # Register our callback
f.test('one') # works
```

Answer (score 0):

To the contrary, everything is "by reference" in Python. But you're copying a reference to `None` into your dictionary, and changing the original slot doesn't do anything to that reference. If you want to retain an extra level of indirection, then the simplest way would be to store strings. If all of your callbacks are attributes of this class, get rid of `map`, and just store a list of callback attribute names. `callback_names = ['cb1', 'cb2']`, and then use `getattr(self, callback_name)()` to invoke the callback. If you must have a map, then you can do `map = {'one': 'cb1', 'two': 'cb2'}`.

You could also do something fancy with properties, but that seems needlessly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

With a delegate descriptor and a bit of attribute trickery.

```
class Delegate(object):
  def __get__(self, instance, owner):
    return instance._cbs.get(self, lambda x: None)

  def __set__(self, instance, value):
    if not hasattr(instance, '_cbs'):
      instance._cbs = {}
    instance._cbs[self] = value

  def __delete__(self, instance):
    if not hasattr(instance, '_cbs'):
      instance._cbs = {}
    instance._cbs[self] = lambda x: None

  def __hash__(self):
    return id(self)

class C(object):
  cb1 = Delegate()
  map = {'one': 'cb1'}

  def test(self, cb):
    getattr(self, self.map[cb])()

def foo():
  print 'bar!'

c = C()
c.cb1 = foo
c.test('one')
```

Comment: Clever, but I suspect the questioner doesn't actually need a solution this complicated.