# TypeError: function(self, item, **kwargs) takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, flask, keyword-argument

I have a function, which puts data into a database, called `new_item()`:

```
def new_item(self, item, **optional):
```

After sending a web form, a function should check the user input and then use this function to put the user input into the database (I'm using Flask, function name is `add_item()`):

```
Market.new_item([request.form['title'], 
                 session.get('user_id'), 
                 request.form['category']], 
                {'desc': request.form['desc'], 
                 'place': request.form['place'], 
                 'price': request.form['price'], 
                 'ono': ono})
```

But I get this error:

```
File X, line 99, in add_item
'ono': ono})
TypeError: new_item() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Fur debugging I print this statement right before I call the function `add_item`. Console output is:

```
([u'iPhone 5', '791465667539154', u'2'], 
 {'price': u'99', 'place': u'Bossental', 'ono': True, 'desc': u'My brand new iPhone'})
```

I really don't know what's wrong. I never worked with `**kwargs` before; is that related to the problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are providing three arguments to the function:

1. The implicit `self` argument, `Market`;
2. The list, which will be `item`; and
3. The dictionary, which causes the problem.

`**optional` is a special argument, that packs all of the keyword arguments not already specified into a dictionary, accessible within the function as `optional` (by convention, this is usually called `kwargs`).

A quick demonstration:

```
>>> def demo(x, y=None, **kwargs):
    print 'x: {0}'.format(x)
    print 'y: {0}'.format(y)
    print 'kwargs: {0}'.format(kwargs)


>>> demo('foo', y='bar', z='baz')
x: foo # 'x' positional argument
y: bar # 'y' keyword argument
kwargs: {'z': 'baz'} # unspecified keyword arguments
```

You can unpack a dictionary into keyword arguments with `**` too:

```
>>> demo('foo', **{'y': 'bar', 'z': 'baz'})
x: foo
y: bar
kwargs: {'z': 'baz'}
```

Therefore if you want to pass the contents of the dictionary into the `**optional` argument, you could use that same syntax to unpack the dictionary into keyword arguments:

```
Market.new_item([request.form['title'], 
                 session.get('user_id'), 
                 request.form['category']], 
                **{'desc': request.form['desc'],
              # ^ note asterisks
                   'place': request.form['place'],
                   'price': request.form['price'],
                   'ono': ono })
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Market.new_item(
    [request.form['title'], session.get('user_id'), request.form['category']], 
    optional={
        'desc': request.form['desc'],
        'place': request.form['place'],
        'price': request.form['price'],
        'ono': ono 
    }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass keyword arguments then you need to specify the argument name while calling the function.

This [link](https://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/keywordArgs.html) has more info on keyword args

May be you need to modify your code to the following. Then it would work

```
Market.new_item([request.form['title'], session.get('user_id'), request.form['category']], 
'desc' = request.form['desc'],
'place' = request.form['place'],
'price' = request.form['price'],
'ono' = ono)
```

Hope this helps!